# Structure of a proof by contradiction

Tags: proof-writing

I know this is a trivial question, but it has been bothering me for a while.

My textbook says "Proof of contradiction exploits the fact that the statement "if A holds, then B holds" is equivalent to the statement "if B does not hold, then A does not hold". So far, okay. But how can we put the proof of $\sqrt2$ being an irrational number into this framework?

Every relevant proof that I've seen derives a contradiction by assuming that $\sqrt2$ is a rational number. In this case, what is the statement B? Is it "$\sqrt2$ is a irrational number"? Then, what is the statement A?

Comment: If you let $B$ be the statement $\sqrt 2$ is irrational, what happens?

Comment: Why not use any of the countless online references for this proof?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In that case, B derives $2p^2 = q^2$, where $\sqrt2 = q/p$ ($p, q$ are integers with the greatest common divisor being 1. Yes, this never be true. But I do not know how to put this into the framework A > B.

Comment: Hi lulu, I am afraid those proofs are not answering my question directly.

Comment: $A$ is the statement that "$\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number", and you show that you can derive a contradiction from that, i.e. a false statement. Usually it's a statement such as "$Q$ and $\neg Q$", meaning a statement and its negation, which cannot both be true. Since $A$ implies a false statement, the negation of that false statement (a true statement) implies $\neg A$.

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you for your comment. Your answer looks reasonable

Answer (score 4):

Statement $A$ (the **assumption**):

- $\sqrt2$ is rational.

Statement $P_1$ (see below):

- There exists coprime positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that
  $\sqrt2=\frac mn.$

Statement $B$:

- There does not exist coprime positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that
  $\sqrt2=\frac mn.$

The **contradiction** lies in the fact that statements $P_1$ and $B$ conflict with each other.

---

**Remarks**

- In this example, the argument goes:

  1. We **assume** that A is true.
  2. Consequently, $P_1$ is true.
  3. Consequently, $P_2$ is true.
  4. Consequently, $P_3$ is true.
  5. $\ldots$
  6. Consequently, $B$ is true.
  7. But $B$ negates $P_1.$ Thus, both statements being true is a
     **contradiction**.
  8. Therefore, $A$ must have been a false assumption, that is, $A$ is actually false.
- In a proof by contradiction, it is sufficient to derive *any*
  contradiction.

  In the above example, we derived two separate
  consequences that conflict with each other;

  in another
  example, we might derive a statement that the angles
  $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ of a flat-plane triangle add up to greater than
  $180^{\circ},$ which conflicts with a well-known theorem.
- Any proof by contrapositive can be recast as a proof by
  contradiction; however, the converse is not true.

  Your book is actually describing a special case of Proof by
  Contradiction (proving a conditional statement using Proof by
  Contrapositive but under the guise of Proof by Contradiction), and
  is therefore being misleading and confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The most common proof proves that if $\sqrt2$ was a rational number $\frac pq$ (with $p,q\in\Bbb N$), then $p$ and $q$ are not coprime. So, in this case, the statement A would be “every rational number can be written as $\frac pq$ with $p\in\Bbb Z$, $q\in\Bbb N$ and $p$ and $q$ coprime”.

Comment: Okay, this is very clear. The proof is "Although the statement A (above) is true, $\sqrt2$ can not be written as $p/q$, which contradicts $\sqrt2$ is a rational number".

Answer (score 3):

***A***:  $\sqrt{2} = \frac{a}{b}$ with $\{ a, b \} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and ${\rm gcd}(a,b) = 1$

***B***:  $2 b^2 = a^2$

Proof of $\neg B$:  By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (unique prime factorization of integers), the left side of ***B*** has an odd number of prime factors.  The right side of ***B*** has an even number of prime factors.  Contradiction.  Therefore $\neg B$.

Therefore $\neg A$.

Comment: Thank you! This is the easiest answer to me! It seems like people have different assumptions or starting points of this proof, which is interesting.

Comment: So perhaps an upvote is in order.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the confusion here is that the terminology is not always used consistently, see for example [What is the difference between “*reductio ad absurdum*” and “*proof by contradiction*”?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/561/what-is-the-difference-between-reductio-ad-absurdum-and-proof-by-contradictio)

> *A textbook says "Proof of contradiction exploits the fact that the statement "if A holds, then B holds" is equivalent to the statement "if B does not hold, then A does not hold""*.

This alone is *not* [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction), but rather [proof by contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive). However, the way it is used in this context, it is combined with a step of [reductio ad absurdum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum) to derive the final result.

Specifically, we can represent the statement "$\sqrt{2}$ *is irrational*" as the implication $A \rightarrow B$ where:

$$
\begin{align}
A \;\;&\equiv\;\; \text{x is } \sqrt{2} \;\;&&\text{(meaning x }\in \mathbb{R}^+ \text{ and } x^2 = 2 \text{)}
\\ B \;\;&\equiv\;\; \text{x is irrational }&& \text{(meaning x } \not\in \mathbb{Q} \iff \not\exists \,p,q \in \mathbb Z \;\big|\; x = \frac{p}{q}\text{ )}
\end{align}
$$

The proof breaks down into two steps:

- $A \rightarrow B\;$ is replaced with the equivalent contrapositive $\;\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A\;$ so what is being proved is that if $x$ is rational then $x^2$ cannot be $2$.
- the contrapositive $\;\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A\;$ is proved by reductio ad absurdum $\;\lnot B \land \lnot\lnot A \rightarrow F$(*alse*) $\;\iff \lnot B \land A \rightarrow F\;$ i.e. assuming $x$ is rational *and* $x^2=2$ results in a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add the logical part, the proof by contradiction is a slightly different formula in propositional logic
$$A\rightarrow B \equiv (A\land \bar{B})\rightarrow F$$ instead of

$$A\rightarrow B \equiv \bar{B} \rightarrow \bar{A}$$

(contraposition) which appears in the textbook. If we take $B$ to be $\bar{A}$ (it can be any proposition that you want) in the proof by contradiction formula, we get

$$A\rightarrow \bar{A} \equiv A\rightarrow F \equiv \bar{A}$$

the classic one. The proofs of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ are based in this formula (by contradiction) and you can also use the contraposition formula if you have two different statements $A$ and $B$ (like in the previous answer, by contraposition)

By the contradiction formula,

$$\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q} \equiv \sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$$

and in plain text would be

"If assuming that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, we show that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational, then $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational". Finally, by number set theory, $\sqrt{2}$ should be irrational.

Answer (score 1):

A related aside: the "proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational" is perhaps better described as the proof that no rational number $r$ exists such that $r^2 = 2$.

We cannot conclude that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational at the end of the proof; only that **if such a number exists, it is not rational**.

The *existence* of $\sqrt{2}$ comes from other considerations.

Answer (score 0):

The proof of the fact that $\sqrt 2$ is irration finally falls back to [The Well Ordering Principle](https://brilliant.org/wiki/the-well-ordering-principle/) (often represented in the form of [Fermat's Law Of Infinite Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20proof%20by,for%20a%20smaller%20number%2C%20leading)). So, what we basically show in this proof is that if there are positive integers (since $\sqrt 2>0$) $p$ and $q$ such that $\sqrt 2=\frac p q$, then **positive integers** $\frac p 2$ and $\frac q 2$ also does the job, i.e., we get an infinite decreasing sequence of positive integers.

So, you may take

**A:** There exists $p,q\in \mathbb N$ such that $\sqrt 2=\frac p q$

**B:** The Well Ordering Principle

Now, we see that $A\implies \neg B$. But, $\neg B$ is absurd because of [Peano's Axioms](https://www.britannica.com/science/Peano-axioms). Hence, $\neg A$.